# How to select columns that dont need grouping by

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the students with the highest grades compared to their brothers/sisters but sql keeps saying i need to group it by their firstname.

```
create table t (
  id int,
  fname  varchar(30),
  lname  varchar(30),
  grade int
);
insert into t VALUES
(3,'peter','yakobo',33),
(2,'ara','yakobo',21),
(1,'war','jones',45),
(0,'ororo','jones',46);

select fname,lname,MAX(grade)
from t
group by lname
```

like for example: in the yakobo family, peter has the highest grade, and in jones family is ororo has the highest grade

Comment: Note: The answers given have the right idea, but you probably want to use RANK(), not ROW_NUMBER(), in case there are duplicates (e.g. two or more people with the same surname got the same grade).

Comment: thanks. I ended up using rank over instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lname ORDER BY grade DESC)
    FROM t
)
SELECT
    id, fname, grade
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

As commented by ZLK:

> You probably want to use `RANK()`, not `ROW_NUMBER()`, in case there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY lname ORDER BY grade DESC
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    ) t4
WHERE rn = 1
```